# Build RViz for ROS2 fails, can't find resource_retriever

Tags: ros2, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed ROS2 Eloquent from Debian packages, I now wanted to build RViz in a separate workspace and cloned the eloquent branch from https://github.com/ros2/rviz.git and ran `colcon build --merge-install`. It fails when building `rviz_rendering` saying

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/eloquent/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:72 (add_executable):
  Target "wrench_visual_test_target" links to target
  "resource_retriever::resource_retriever" but the target was not found.
  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an
  ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/eloquent/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:55 (_ament_add_gmock)
  CMakeLists.txt:260 (ament_add_gmock)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/eloquent/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:72 (add_executable):
  Target "line_test_target" links to target
  "resource_retriever::resource_retriever" but the target was not found.
  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an
  ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/eloquent/share/ament_cmake_gmock/cmake/ament_add_gmock.cmake:55 (_ament_add_gmock)
  CMakeLists.txt:249 (ament_add_gmock)
```

Not sure why it can't find resource_retriever, when I check /opt/ros/eloquent/share/ a resource_retriever directory exists. My ament_cmake_gmock version is

```
$ apt list ros-eloquent-ament-cmake-gmock
Listing... Done
ros-eloquent-ament-cmake-gmock/bionic,now 0.8.2-1bionic.20200605.223611 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Does someone know how this fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360975/build-rviz-for-ros2-fails,-can%27t-find-resource_retriever/) by [eloquent-fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/56547/eloquent-fox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering my own question: The gmock library was not installed on my computer. After making sure that libgmock.a is in /usr/lib, it worked.

---

Originally posted by [eloquent-fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/56547/eloquent-fox/) with karma: 25 on 2020-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0